# FPDF problems when submitting form

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

I'm having some problems when writing my form input to PDF it's coming up with the error;

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare hex2dec() (previously declared in /home/tomjk/public_html/release/WriteHTML.php:12) in /home/tomjk/public_html/release/WriteHTML.php on line 24

I've had a look at the php file and it looks absolutely fine.... I've been following a tutorial over at PHP gang and no one else has seem to come across this.

http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-in-php-with-fpdf_447.html

fpdf.php

```
<?php
require('WriteHTML.php');
include('config.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM `release` ORDER BY `id` ";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$pdf=new PDF_HTML();

$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 15);

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('RR_logo.png',18,13,33);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
$pdf->WriteHTML('<para><h1>PHPGang Programming Blog, Tutorials, jQuery, Ajax, PHP, MySQL and Demos</h1><br>
Website: <u>www.phpgang.com</u></para><br><br>How to Convert HTML to PDF with fpdf example');

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',7); 
$htmlTable='Talent Details<hr />
Talent name '. $POST['name'] .' (hereafter referred to as “Talent”)<br />
Email '. $POST['email'] .' <br />   
Phone no '. $POST['phone'] .' <br />

Producers Details<hr />
Producer’s name '. $row['producers'] .' (hereafter referred to as “Producer”)<br />
Production Company '. $row['release'] .'<br />
Title '. $row['company'] .'(all hereafter referred to as “Production”)<br />


';
$pdf->WriteHTML2("<br><br><br>$htmlTable");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',6);
$pdf->Output(); 
?>
```

WriteHTML.php

```
<?php
//HTML2PDF by Clément Lavoillotte
//ac.lavoillotte@noos.fr
//webmaster@streetpc.tk
//http://www.streetpc.tk

require('fpdf.php');

//function hex2dec
//returns an associative array (keys: R,G,B) from
//a hex html code (e.g. #3FE5AA)
function hex2dec($couleur = "#000000"){
    $R = substr($couleur, 1, 2);
    $rouge = hexdec($R);
    $V = substr($couleur, 3, 2);
    $vert = hexdec($V);
    $B = substr($couleur, 5, 2);
    $bleu = hexdec($B);
    $tbl_couleur = array();
    $tbl_couleur['R']=$rouge;
    $tbl_couleur['V']=$vert;
    $tbl_couleur['B']=$bleu;
    return $tbl_couleur;
}

//conversion pixel -> millimeter at 72 dpi
function px2mm($px){
    return $px*25.4/72;
}

function txtentities($html){
    $trans = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
    $trans = array_flip($trans);
    return strtr($html, $trans);
}
////////////////////////////////////

class PDF_HTML extends FPDF
{
//variables of html parser
var $B;
var $I;
var $U;
var $HREF;
var $fontList;
var $issetfont;
var $issetcolor;

function PDF_HTML($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $format='A4')
{
    //Call parent constructor
    $this->FPDF($orientation,$unit,$format);
    //Initialization
    $this->B=0;
    $this->I=0;
    $this->U=0;
    $this->HREF='';
    $this->fontlist=array('arial', 'times', 'courier', 'helvetica', 'symbol');
    $this->issetfont=false;
    $this->issetcolor=false;
}

function WriteHTML($html)
{
    //HTML parser
    $html=strip_tags($html,"<b><u><i><a><img><p><br><strong><em><font><tr><blockquote>"); //supprime tous les tags sauf ceux reconnus
    $html=str_replace("\n",' ',$html); //remplace retour à la ligne par un espace
    $a=preg_split('/<(.*)>/U',$html,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE); //éclate la chaîne avec les balises
    foreach($a as $i=>$e)
    {
        if($i%2==0)
        {
            //Text
            if($this->HREF)
                $this->PutLink($this->HREF,$e);
            else
                $this->Write(5,stripslashes(txtentities($e)));
        }
        else
        {
            //Tag
            if($e[0]=='/')
                $this->CloseTag(strtoupper(substr($e,1)));
            else
            {
                //Extract attributes
                $a2=explode(' ',$e);
                $tag=strtoupper(array_shift($a2));
                $attr=array();
                foreach($a2 as $v)
                {
                    if(preg_match('/([^=]*)=["\']?([^"\']*)/',$v,$a3))
                        $attr[strtoupper($a3[1])]=$a3[2];
                }
                $this->OpenTag($tag,$attr);
            }
        }
    }
}

function OpenTag($tag, $attr)
{
    //Opening tag
    switch($tag){
        case 'STRONG':
            $this->SetStyle('B',true);
            break;
        case 'EM':
            $this->SetStyle('I',true);
            break;
        case 'B':
        case 'I':
        case 'U':
            $this->SetStyle($tag,true);
            break;
        case 'A':
            $this->HREF=$attr['HREF'];
            break;
        case 'IMG':
            if(isset($attr['SRC']) && (isset($attr['WIDTH']) || isset($attr['HEIGHT']))) {
                if(!isset($attr['WIDTH']))
                    $attr['WIDTH'] = 0;
                if(!isset($attr['HEIGHT']))
                    $attr['HEIGHT'] = 0;
                $this->Image($attr['SRC'], $this->GetX(), $this->GetY(), px2mm($attr['WIDTH']), px2mm($attr['HEIGHT']));
            }
            break;
        case 'TR':
        case 'BLOCKQUOTE':
        case 'BR':
            $this->Ln(5);
            break;
        case 'P':
            $this->Ln(10);
            break;
        case 'FONT':
            if (isset($attr['COLOR']) && $attr['COLOR']!='') {
                $coul=hex2dec($attr['COLOR']);
                $this->SetTextColor($coul['R'],$coul['V'],$coul['B']);
                $this->issetcolor=true;
            }
            if (isset($attr['FACE']) && in_array(strtolower($attr['FACE']), $this->fontlist)) {
                $this->SetFont(strtolower($attr['FACE']));
                $this->issetfont=true;
            }
            break;
    }
}

function CloseTag($tag)
{
    //Closing tag
    if($tag=='STRONG')
        $tag='B';
    if($tag=='EM')
        $tag='I';
    if($tag=='B' || $tag=='I' || $tag=='U')
        $this->SetStyle($tag,false);
    if($tag=='A')
        $this->HREF='';
    if($tag=='FONT'){
        if ($this->issetcolor==true) {
            $this->SetTextColor(0);
        }
        if ($this->issetfont) {
            $this->SetFont('arial');
            $this->issetfont=false;
        }
    }
}

function SetStyle($tag, $enable)
{
    //Modify style and select corresponding font
    $this->$tag+=($enable ? 1 : -1);
    $style='';
    foreach(array('B','I','U') as $s)
    {
        if($this->$s>0)
            $style.=$s;
    }
    $this->SetFont('',$style);
}

function PutLink($URL, $txt)
{
    //Put a hyperlink
    $this->SetTextColor(0,0,255);
    $this->SetStyle('U',true);
    $this->Write(5,$txt,$URL);
    $this->SetStyle('U',false);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
}

}//end of class
?>
```

Comment: Which line is line 24 in WriteHTML.php?

Comment: line 24 is the "}" after return $tbl_couleur;

Comment: As i know assigning a value in the method segnature do not work. So try to chang `function hex2dec($couleur = "#000000"){` to `function hex2dec($couleur){`

Comment: Still showing the same error

Comment: Think I figured out what it is i've required fpdf in WriteHTML.php and WriteHTML in fpdf so they are looping....

Comment: look at my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Think you have the Problem because fpdf.php require WriteHTML.php and  WriteHTML.php require fpdf.php. so you have a cycle in dependencies.

You should try to Change this.